# How destroy and recreate a lua_State

Tags: c++, lua

For a school project, I'm using Lua to add some scripting functionality to a game engine.  The engine is quite slow to load, so rather than having to restart it every time I change one of my Lua scripts, I'd like to be able to just reload the scripts.  I'd like to be able to do this in a way which is safe and reliable even if other script authors have polluted the global state in unpredictable ways.

In my mind, the easiest way to go about it is to simply destroy the `lua_State` in my C++ code, and then create a new one, re-bind my functions and reload all of the necessary scripts.  However, I'm having some trouble getting it work properly.  I have a class which serves as an interface to the Lua virtual machine, which has the following constructor and destructor:

```
LuaInterface::LuaInterface()
{
  luaVM = lua_open();
  luaL_openlibs(luaVM);

  // Create the ortsgfx table.
  lua_newtable(luaVM);
  lua_setglobal(luaVM, TABLE_NAME);
}

LuaInterface::~LuaInterface()
{
  // Close the Lua virtual machine
  lua_close(luaVM);
}
```

Note that lua_close(luaVM) is called when the object's destructor executes.  I attempt to reset Lua from the game engine with the following code:

```
lua.~LuaInterface();
lua = LuaInterface();
initLua();
```

(Lua is a LuaInterface object, of course.)  This causes a segmentation fault in `initLua()` when I try to initialize one of my tables.  **However, if I remove the `lua_close(luaVM)` call in the destructor, then everything works fine.**

What am I doing wrong?  Additionally, is there a better way to go about reloading my Lua scripts?

Comment: Does lua_close() do any memory de-allocation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have experience with C++, but not Lua, so here's my guess:

Your `LuaInterface` class might not implement an assignment operator and copy constructor, otherwise you would probably have posted them along with the default constructor and destructor. See the Rule of Three:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

If that is so, then this line is what causes the error:

```
lua = LuaInterface();
```

Because `LuaInterface()` on the right will construct a temporary instance, and the automatically generated `operator=` will copy the `lua_State` over into `lua`. After this line, the unnamed temporary on the right-hand side is destroyed and frees the same `lua_State` that `lua` also believes to own.

Three solutions come to mind:

- Make `LuaInterface` noncopyable by declaring a private copy constructor and assignment operator, and never implementing them. (This is relatively common: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/bigtwo2.html) Then add a `LuaInterface.reset()` member function that does the same as the destructor, followed by the constructor would do. You can keep your code clean by moving shared parts to a private `init()` function. (Beware of using C++ exceptions in this function, leaving the object in an invalid state.)
- Make `LuaInterface` noncopyable, but instead of having a `LuaInterface lua` variable, use a pointer or a `boost::optional<LuaInterface> lua`. That way, you can destroy and recreate the variable without manually calling the destructor.
- Make `LuaInterface` a shared reference class by using the new `std::shared_ptr`. You just use a `std::shared_ptr<LuaState> luaVM` member variable instead of a raw pointer, and in the constructor you call:

  `luaVM.reset(lua_open(), lua_close);`

  You do not even need a destructor in this case, but you should read up on `shared_ptr` and what the automatically generated members do now.

With either of these three solutions, you can then use simple assignment to recreate the state:

```
lua = LuaInterface();
```

Now I hope the problem is really on C++'s, and not on Lua's side. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the source for `initLua` so I can only guess, but...

You usually shouldn't just play willy-nilly with constructors and destructors like that. Just do

```
lua = LuaInterface();
initLua();
```

The class should have an assignment operator to take care of the `lua_State`s it owns.

Answer (score 3):

```
lua.~LuaInterface(); 
lua = LuaInterface(); 
initLua();
```

This is Undefined Behaviour. You should do simply `lua = LuaInterface();`. You have *other* problems with not adhering to the Rule of Three, but this is UB as well.

Comment: The only sensible things to do after directly calling the destructor is to reinitialize the variable with placement new or deallocate the memory occupied by the variable, but even that wouldn't make sense here, as that directly calling the destructor is only sensible after initializing the variable with placement new...

Answer (score 1):

(Greetings from the future! I ended up here from another Lua question, but I was shocked to see the question so poorly addressed. Hopefully I can help future visitors to this question.)

If you're going to do an in-place destruction, you need to follow up with an in-place construction. Your approach is wrong.

```
 lua.~LuaInterface();
 new (&lua) LuaInterface();
```

From there, I would recommend you familiarize yourself with C++11 move-semantics. Then, you can make the class work using pretty syntax.

```
lua = LuaInterface();
// Destructs old instance. Constructs new one. Moves into your variable.
```

While I would not recommend using placement destructor and placement new, you *could* implement your assignment operator that way.

```
LuaInterface& LuaInterface::operator=(LuaInterface&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        this->~LuaInterface();
        new (this) LuaInterface(other);
    }

    return *this;
}
```